# Loop posts excerpt returns empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm displaying my posts list this way:

```
[-- IMAGE --]
[-- Title --]
[-- Excerpt --]
[-- "Read more" --]
```

My code was working fine when I was using it inside the `index.php` file, like:

```
while(have_posts())
{
    the_post();

    $link = get_permalink();
    $title = the_title();
    $excerpt = the_excerpt();
}
```

And then in the `functions.php` I have a filter applied to the excerpt:

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

function custom_excerpt_length() 
{
    return 14;
}

function new_excerpt_more($more) 
{
    global $post;

    return '... <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more</a>';
}
```

However, now I have to loop through the posts inside the `functions.php` and I have figure it out for the title and link but not for the excerpt.

```
$posts  = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $post)
{
    $link = get_permalink($post);
    $title = get_the_title($post);
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post); // Returns empty and I'd like to apply the filters   
}
```

How do I apply the filters to the function `get_the_excerpt` and why is it empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt):

> If this function is used outside The Loop and the post doesn't have a
>   custom excerpt, this function will use [wp_trim_excerpt()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) to generate
>   an excerpt. That function uses [get_the_content()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content), which must be used
>   with The Loop and will cause problems if get_the_excerpt() is being
>   used outside The Loop. In order to avoid the issues, use
>   [setup_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) prior to calling get_the_excerpt() to set up the
>   global $post object.

This should work:

```
$posts  = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $post)
{
    setup_postdata($post);

    $link = get_permalink($post);
    $title = get_the_title($post);
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post);
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```